# помогите решить проблему, не работает переадресация на другой сайт нужно в php

Tags: php

[image: не работает переадресация на php]

помогите решить проблему, не работает переадресация на другой сайт нужно в php

Comment: `<?` -> `<?php` ???????

Comment: пробывал с  <?php тоже не идет

Comment: тогда какая ошибка у вас?

Comment: включи показ ошибок: https://karashchuk.com/PHP/error_reporting-display_errors-display_startup_errors/

Comment: Перед открывающим тегом не должно быть _ничего_. У вас есть как минимум один перевод строки. И первое что нужно делать перед тем как задавать вопрос - смотреть в логи. Если там ничего нет, смотреть работают-ли они

Comment: Как вариант - UTF-8 with BOM. Из-за него появляется печатаемый символ. Функция `header` работать не будет